# Wait for input from called application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, process.start

I have a third-part programme named Sample.exe which I would like to run from my C# application. The code for running the programme is below. The problem is, that the code doesn't wait for the input of the programme and skips it. I need it to wait for input when the first menu is shown, and then wait for input when second menu appears. How could I do it?

```
        Process sortProcess = new Process();
        sortProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"Sample.exe";

        // Set UseShellExecute to false for redirection.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        // Redirect the standard output of the sort command.   
        // This stream is read asynchronously using an event handler.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        StringBuilder sortOutput = new StringBuilder("");

        // Set our event handler to asynchronously read the sort output.
        sortProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

        // Redirect standard input as well.  This stream 
        // is used synchronously.
        sortProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        // Start the process.
        sortProcess.Start();

        // Use a stream writer to synchronously write the sort input.
        StreamWriter sortStreamWriter = sortProcess.StandardInput;
        // Start the asynchronous read of the sort output stream.
        sortProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

        // End the input stream to the sort command.
        sortStreamWriter.Close();

        // Wait for the sort process to write the sorted text lines.
        sortProcess.WaitForExit();
        sortProcess.Close();
    }

    private static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, 
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // Collect the sort command output. 
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
        {
            string str = outLine.Data;
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }
```